# Integral over $\Sigma$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to calculate the integral $\int_{\Sigma}(2x \ dy\land dz + 2y \ dz\land dx + (x^2+y^2) \ dx\land dy$, where $\Sigma$ is the boundary of the bounded space $D$ that is defined by $0\leq z\leq 1-x^2-y^2$ and has such an orientation that the perpendicular vectors have direction to the outside of the space $D$.

Do we use here cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: I want to calculate the integral $$\int_{\Sigma}(2x \ dy\land dz + 2y \ dz\land dx + (x^2+y^2) \ dx\land dy$$ @RobertZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Use [Stokes' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes'_theorem),
$$\int_{\partial D} \omega  = \int_{D}d\omega.$$
Here 
$$\omega = F_1 dy \wedge dz + F_2 dz \wedge dx +F_3 dx \wedge dy,$$
with $\mathbf{F}=(F_1,F_2,F_3)=(2x,2y,x^2+y^2)$ and $\Sigma=\partial D$. Then the given integral is
$$\iint_{\Sigma}\mathbf{F} d\mathbf{S}=\int_{\partial D} \omega =\int_{D}d\omega=\iiint_D \operatorname{div}(\mathbf{F}) dV=\iiint_D(2+2+0)dV=4|D|$$
where $|D|$ is the volume of $D$.

Comment: Can we not in this case the formula $$\iint_{\Sigma}(P dy\land dz+Q dz\land dx + Rdx\land dy)=\iint_D\left (P(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v))\frac{\partial{(y,z)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}+Q(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v))\frac{\partial{(z,x)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}+R(x(u, v), y(u, v), z(u, v))\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u, v)}}\right )d\theta dz$$ ?

Comment: So, can we use only Stoke's Theorem and not the formula above?

Comment: the result must be $\frac{8\pi}{3}$

Comment: So follow my hint and you will get the result easily.

Comment: But how we calculate the volume of $D$ ? Dowe have to  parametrize the space?

Comment: @MaryStar Is $D$ given by $0\leq z\leq 1-x^2-y^2$ or $0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$??

Comment: The first one, without the root.

Comment: Which book is taken from? I get the result $\frac{8\pi}{3}$ when $0\leq z\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$. Could you check the statement once more please?

Comment: It is not from a book, it is a pdf with such exercises. It must be a typo then! Thank you so much for noticing it!! :-)